# Incorrect coordinates, not adding correctly

Tags: c++, loops, coordinates

I am simply trying to move the cursor from Point A to Point B. This proves to be fine until I have tried using a coordinate in which the Y value starts to decrease when it's suppose to increase. I am baffled because as far as I can tell I have the if statements set correctly.

For example, I set beginning X,Y coords to 0,0 and ending coords 1920,1080. It moves diagonal across the screen just fine. Vice versa, it moves from 1920,1080 to 0,0 just fine. When I had these coordinates set(in example below), that is when the problems occurred & I realized it wasn't working correctly. I changed the SetCursorPos to an std::cout to look into the issue and my Y coord is moving into the negatives.

I have pondered on this for a few days and just can't seem to figure this out. I am sure it's a simple solution that I am overlooking.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>

template<typename T>
void move(T x, T y, const T& nx, const T& ny)
{
    T run = nx - x, rise = ny - y, addX = 0, addY = 0;
    if(run > rise)
    {
        addX = run / rise;
        addY++;
    }
    else
    {
        addX++;
        addY = rise / run;
    }

    while(x != nx && y != ny)
    {
        if(x < nx)
        {
            x += addX;
            if(x > nx)x = nx;
        }
        else if (x > nx)
        {
            x -= addX;
            if(x < nx)x = nx;
        }
        if(y < ny)
        {
            y += addY;
            if(y > ny)y = ny;
        }
        else if (y > ny)
        {
            y -= addY;
            if(y < ny)y = ny;
        }

        std::cout << "X: " << x << " Y: " << y << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1));
    }
}

int main()
{ 
    move<double>(790,310,595,650);
    while(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are either adding or subtracting addX and addY depending on whether they are less than or greater than nx and ny, they need to always be positive values. So just compute the absolute value of rise and run before computing addX and addY:

```
T run = nx - x, rise = ny - y, addX = 0, addY = 0;
if(run < 0)
    run = -run;
if(rise < 0)
    rise = -rise;
```

Comment: Or `T run = abs(nx - x)`!